React useState boolean not updating
I am trying to create a custom toast to show error notification.
Toast visibility is depends on the isShowed from the props.
export type ToastProps = {
  color: 'error' | 'success' | 'warning';
  message: string;
  isShowed: boolean;
};

const Toast = (props: ToastProps) => {
  const { color, message, isShowed } = props;

  const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false);

  console.log(isShowed, showed);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isShowed) {
      setShowed(true);
    } else {
      setShowed(false);
    }
  }, [isShowed]);

  return (
    <div
      className="toast-notification-wrapper"
      style={{
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '20px',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
        zIndex: 9999,
        padding: '15px',
        borderRadius: '5px',
        transition: 'all 0.3s ease-out',
        opacity: showed ? 1 : 0,
        pointerEvents: showed ? 'auto' : 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        minWidth: '150px',
        backgroundColor:
          color === 'error'
            ? '#dc3545'
            : color === 'success'
            ? '#28a745'
            : '#ffc107',
      }}
    >
      <p style={{ margin: 0, color: 'white', fontSize: '15px', lineHeight: 1 }}>
        {message}
      </p>
      <span
        style={{
          cursor: 'pointer',
          display: 'flex',
          alignContent: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          marginLeft: '30px',
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          setShowed(!isShowed);
        }}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faClose}
          style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: '15px' }}
        />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

This is my toast components
const Login = (props: { isCompleted: boolean; isLoggedIn: boolean }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [toast, setToast] = useState({
    isShowed: false,
    color: 'error',
    message: 'failed',
  } as ToastProps);

  const { isCompleted, isLoggedIn } = props;

  if (isCompleted === false) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    navigate('/');
  }

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword(showPassword ? false : true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await login({ username, password });

      window.location.href = '/';
    } catch (error: any) {
      setToast({
        isShowed: true,
        color: 'error',
        message:
          error.response.data?.message ||
          'Unexpected Error. Please try again later',
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-form">
      <Toast
        isShowed={toast.isShowed}
        color={toast.color}
        message={toast.message}
      ></Toast>
      <div className="login-form-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-row">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your username"
              required={true}
              onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
          </div>

          <div className="form-row">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
              placeholder="********"
              required={true}
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <span
              onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                right: '20px',
                top: 'calc(50% + 12px)',
                fontSize: '13px',
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={showPassword ? faEyeSlash : faEye}
                style={{ color: 'black' }}
              />
            </span>
          </div>

          <div className="button-wrapper">
            <button value={'Login'}>Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const Login = (props: { isCompleted: boolean; isLoggedIn: boolean }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [toast, setToast] = useState({
    isShowed: false,
    color: 'error',
    message: 'failed',
  } as ToastProps);

  const { isCompleted, isLoggedIn } = props;

  if (isCompleted === false) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    navigate('/');
  }

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword(showPassword ? false : true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await login({ username, password });

      window.location.href = '/';
    } catch (error: any) {
      setToast({
        isShowed: true,
        color: 'error',
        message:
          error.response.data?.message ||
          'Unexpected Error. Please try again later',
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-form">
      <Toast
        isShowed={toast.isShowed}
        color={toast.color}
        message={toast.message}
      ></Toast>
      <div className="login-form-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-row">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your username"
              required={true}
              onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
          </div>

          <div className="form-row">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
              placeholder="********"
              required={true}
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <span
              onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                right: '20px',
                top: 'calc(50% + 12px)',
                fontSize: '13px',
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={showPassword ? faEyeSlash : faEye}
                style={{ color: 'black' }}
              />
            </span>
          </div>

          <div className="button-wrapper">
            <button value={'Login'}>Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

and this is my login form components
The toast notification worked the first time when error event triggerd.
But when the error occurred again, the toast remained invisible.
When I use the console.log to check the state, the isShowed from props is true, but the showed is false.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

update the close button logic to setShowed(false) when the user clicks the close button, rather than toggling it based on !isShowed. Also I believe you have a mismatch between the prop and the state, they are inconsistent.

@IdrisSelimi Hi, I had updated the button logic, but it is still not working after the first display. For the prop and state, I found that there will be true for isShowed and false  for showed, how do I make sure they are consistent?

You're updating the isShowed state within the Toast component, but since isShowed is coming from the parent as a prop, you should only control that state in the parent. The Toast component should simply render based on the isShowed prop passed to it.

Update:
I changed the useEffect to listen to props value changing instead of isShowed
useEffect(() => {
    if (isShowed) {
      setShowed(true);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowed(false);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [props]);

The previous version listened for changes in isShowed, but since the value was changing in props, so the data was not updating in useEffect dependency array.

remove useEffect block and showed state from Toast component, use following  ToastProps
export type ToastProps = {
  color: 'error' | 'success' | 'warning';
  message: string;
  handleCloseToast: ()=>void
};

use this handleCloseToast function to close toast
and based on your toast state in parent,  use following Toast props
<Toast
        handleCloseToast={() => setToast(prev => ({...prev,isShowed:false})}
        color={toast.color}
        message={toast. Message}
 ></Toast>

This is just code form of what @IdrisSelimi was explaining

Your useEffect code is off. It triggers on component mount and each time this component re-renders. Each time isShowed updates your useEffect updates it again but to the same value which triggers a re-render which triggers useEffect again, which is a bad infinite loop. You could just get rid of the useEffect and call your setter function from within some event like onClick or from a callback in a function, depending on how you wanna implement it.
